# wordpress contact from 7 popup, if we submitted another from

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

If I submit a form successfully then it will popup other from . Was there any Form Plugin in WordPress like that? Now it is submitted succefully or not it was popup a from .Because I am using [submit "Next"] in http://consumercreditcardrelief.com/home/. I am wanted a if it is submitted successfully in then i t will popup other form. Is it possible?

Comment: I am using this type of mechanism now <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="background-color: #0b486c !important;">[submit "Next"]</botton> in  http://consumercreditcardrelief.com/

Comment: Please add supplemental information by editing your question, not in comments, thank you. Also make sure there are no distracting typos.